# flask panda displaying data on a table from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, flask

I cant seem to get the following code to display the returned data from mysql query.

I have tested and made sure its returning data, though the jsonify
complains with an error when the data is not a string.

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

Python

```
@app.route('/SalesSummary', methods= ['GET',  'POST'])
def SalesSummary():
    data=Receipts()
    return render_template('salessummary.html',data=data)   

@app.route('/SalesSummary', methods= ['GET',  'POST'])
def Receipts():    
    c, conn = connection()
    data = c.execute("select * from SB.receipts")    
    data = c.fetchall()
    return jsonify(data)
```

HTML (SalesSummary)
Script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function get_temps() {
                $.getJSON("SalesSummary",
                        function (data) {
                            $('#Date').text(data.receipt_date)
                            $('#RctRef').text(data.receipt_ref)
                            $('#Total').text(data.receipt_total_amount)
                            $('#Cash').text(data.receipt_total_amount);
                            $('#Card').text(data.receipt_total_amount)
                            $('#Cheque').text(data.receipt_total_amount)
                           $('#MobileMoney').text(data.receipt_total_amount)
                            $('#OnAcount').text(data.receipt_total_amount);

                        }
                );
            }
</script>
```

Html table to display the data.

```
<body class="no-skin">
<table id="dynamic-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
       <tr>
       <th class="center">Date</th>
            <th>Rct Ref</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Cash</th>
            <th>Card</th>
            <th>Cheque</th>
            <th>Mobile Money</th>
            <th>OnAcount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="Date"></td>                                                   
          <td id="RctRef"></td>                                                 
          <td id="Total"></td>                                                  
          <td id="Cash"></td>                                                   
          <td id="Card"></td>                                                   
          <td id="Cheque"></td>                                                 
          <td id="MobileMoney"></td>                                                    
          <td id="OnAcount"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.